# Use of yet in the middle of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I found the following example that I'm unsure of its correctness.

> The goals of X are to establish a theoretically well-founded yet practical and comprehensible Y.

I've searched for the uses of yet and this one, albeit completely understandable, does not appear.

Comment: First hit on [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet): *yet* _(conjunction)_ 
"but nevertheless; cf _but_"

Comment: But in here if I replace by "but" it doesn't seems to make sense, right?

Comment: I think it does. "but nevertheless" is slightly better than "but", though.

Answer (score 1):

TL,DR It's a poor example of *yet* usage because it is based on an idiomatic relationship between *theory* and *practice* that conflicts with the formal register being used for the expression of goals.

To a native speaker, this use is basically ignored. It means *and*, but reminds us of the longstanding idea that theory and practice are often regarded as in conflict.

To be clear, the writer did not need to use *yet* here. "The goals of X are to establish a theoretically well-founded, practical and comprehensible Y" is in many ways a more satisfactory sentence.

Furthermore, I associate comprehension with theory more so than practice, so it's on the wrong side of the *yet* if you parse it as " [...] a theoretically well-founded, (practical and comprehensible) Y." To get it to parse as "[...] (a theoretically well-founded yet practical) and comprehensible Y" I would replace the *and* with a comma. That distances the *comprehensible* from the *yet*.

Comment: I understand the issue you raise but the question was grammatical, not semantical. I agree it could be written with "and", but the meaning of the phrase would be changed by doing so (I don't want to discuss if practice and theoretical are somewhat conflicted, depends on the context, in here, it is about applied mathematics).